# Computer won't start back up.

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, battery, power

I unplugged everything from my computer a couple of days ago because I had to move it. After half an hour later I plugged everything back but my computer wouldn't start. It's a HP desktop. Here are the things I noticed or have done.

> 1. The power button's light used to be lit when power cord is plugged in and it isn't anymore.
> 2. I pressed the power button and nothing happened.
> 3. The power supply has a green light. When I plugged in the power cord, the green light is on.
> 4. I followed steps posted on the internet to test if a power supply is still working. I unplugged all lines that are connected to the
>      power supply and used a pin to connect green and blank wire and
>      plugged in the power cord of the power supply. The fan was running
>      fine.
> 5. I changed the cmos battery.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you missed a connection somewhere. Unplug everything again and start from the beginning. Also make sure that the power supply's on/off switch is set to on (usually at the back of the computer)

That's all I can think of. Otherwise, to eliminate any connection faults, try to see if there is a power on button directly on your motherboard. If it turns on, then your issue is with the connection between the button and the motherboard